# Can I wirelessy copy my videos from iPhone to Mac?

Tags: ios, mac, video

Is there a way to wirelessy transfer the videos I made on iPhone or iPad to my Mac (to iPhoto or Logic Pro), or is the only option to use a cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Photo Transfer App](http://www.phototransferapp.com/)

> Easily transfer photos and videos between iPhone, iPad, Android and Computer.
>   No cables or extra software required.

$2.99 in the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Won't the iOS 5 [Wireless Sync](http://www.apple.com/ios/features.html#pcfree) do exactly what you want?

Comment: It doesn't work for videos I made with my iPhone camera (only iTunes videos)